# Printing All The Files Path's In C:\ With C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, filesystems

I tried to print all the files path's in C:.
But I saw that I am getting permission errors.

```
void getAllFilesInDirectory(wstring directoryPath, vector<wstring> &files) {
    for (filesystem::directory_entry directory : filesystem::directory_iterator(directoryPath)) {


        if (GetFileAttributesW(directory.path().wstring().c_str()) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
            continue;

        //Checking if directory.path is a file or a directory
        if (GetFileAttributesW(directory.path().wstring().c_str()) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) {
            files.push_back(directory.path().wstring());
            wcout << "The path is " << directory.path().wstring() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        try {
            for (filesystem::directory_entry file : filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory)) {


                if (GetFileAttributesW(file.path().wstring().c_str()) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    continue;
                }


                wcout << "The path of the file is " << file.path().wstring() << endl;
                files.push_back(file.path().wstring());
            }
        } catch (exception &e) {
            wcout << "There is exception " << e.what() << " and the directory path is: " << directory.path().wstring()
                  << endl;

        }
    }
}
```

My code is working when I give the function a regular directory (not one with privileges).

But when I give him "C:\" he quitting  after printing a little path's.

It will be great if someone post his method for printing all the path's in the C drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running your program elevated ("as Administrator").

Comment: Do you understand what the "permission errors" mean?  This seems to be a question about navigating one's operating system, more than programming.

Comment: "permission error" means access denied. I want that my code will ignore files that he doesn't have access to them, but I didn't succeeded.

Comment: It looks like maybe you need another try/catch block around your outer loop.

Comment: You may need to [edit] your question, for clarity.  In your question, you ask how to "print all the paths", but I now suspect you may want to instead skip paths that the OS forbids access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in comments that:

> I want that my code will ignore files that he doesn't have access to them

`std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` both have a constructor that accepts a [`std::filesystem::directory_options`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options) enum as input, which has a `skip_permission_denied` item available for that purpose, for example:

```cpp
void getAllFilesInDirectory(const wstring &directoryPath, vector<wstring> &files) {
    for (filesystem::directory_entry directory : filesystem::directory_iterator(directoryPath, filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
        ...
        for (filesystem::directory_entry file : filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory, filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, you may want to consider adding a namespace alias to shorten those qualified names, eg:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

for (fs::directory_entry directory : fs::directory_iterator(directoryPath, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
    ...
    for (fs::directory_entry file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, your use of `GetFileAttributesW()` is wrong. You are not checking for errors, and you are not taking into account that folders and files can (and usually do) have multiple attributes assigned. Use the `&` (AND) operator when testing for specific attributes. And testing for the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` attribute is not the correct way to differentiate a file from a folder. Test for the presence/lack of the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` attribute instead.

Try this:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void getAllFilesInDirectory(const wstring &directoryPath, vector<wstring> &files) {
    for (fs::directory_entry directory : fs::directory_iterator(directoryPath, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {

        DWORD attrs = GetFileAttributesW(directory.path().wstring().c_str());

        if (attrs == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            wcerr << "Error " << err << " getting attributes for path " << directory.path().wstring() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
            continue;

        //Checking if directory.path is a file or a directory
        if (attrs & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            files.push_back(directory.path().wstring());
            wcout << "The path is " << directory.path().wstring() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        try {
            for (fs::directory_entry file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {

                attrs = GetFileAttributesW(file.path().wstring().c_str());

                if (attrs == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
                    DWORD err = GetLastError();
                    wcerr << "Error " << err << " getting attributes for path " << file.path().wstring() << endl;
                    continue;
                }

                if (attrs & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                    continue;

                wcout << "The path of the file is " << file.path().wstring() << endl;
                files.push_back(file.path().wstring());
            }
        } catch (const exception &e) {
            wcout << "There is exception " << e.what() << " and the directory path is: " << directory.path().wstring() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the best!